# XSLT How to trim space before and after an element, when the element says to?

Tags: xslt, xpath

This problem emerges in formatting text documents that use TEI markup (www.tei-c.org). It is beyond my XSLT/XPATH skills. (A solution in XSLT/XPATH 1.0 is required.)

There is a mark-up element, `<lb>`, that marks line breaks. It can take an attribute `@break`. If `@break="no"`, then any space between the `<lb>` and surrounding text should be ignored when generating output.

So

```
This little tea <lb break="no" />
pot, short and stout.
```

should be understood as

```
This little teapot, short and stout.
```

That is, the space after "tea" and the newline before "pot" should not be rendering in the output stream.

For the space before the `<lb>`, this could work:

```
<xsl:template match="text()[following-sibling::*[1][self::lb[@break='no']]">
    <!-- Do something about the space here. -->
</xsl:template>
```

Something similar would work for the newline after the `<lb>`.

OK. But this is trickier:

```
This <emph>little <ref>tea </ref> </emph>
<lb break="no" />
pot, short and stout.
```

Now the text inside the `<ref>` element is not a sibling of `<lb>`. And the space before `</ref>`, the space before `</emph>` and the newlines before and after the `<lb>` all need to be excised from the output stream.

How?

Comment: Tough. I assume that if `<lb...>` was not there the spaces before `</ref>` and before `</emph>` should remain in the output, correct?

Comment: Yes. It would probably be bad practice if both of those two were there, but the whitespace definitely could appear in either place and would need to be preserved if `<lb break="no">` were not there.

Comment: I'm thinking it might be a messy solution, but you could use the translate() function to remove spaces from nodes you know shouldn't have them. Could you post an excerpt from your actual xml with a before-and-after similar to the teapot example?

Comment: Ambiguity: if there was non-space text between `</ref>` and `</emph>`, would you still need to remove the whitespace before `</ref>`?

Comment: translate may be difficult with line breaks and tabs...  I think you need more than one template (see revised answer below)

Comment: Next ambiguity: in `tea <lb/> <lb break="no"/> pot`, should the space before `<lb/>` be removed? (I'm teasing out the definition of "surrounding text.")

Answer (score 3):

Here's a tested, working implementation, including how to trim whitespace from the right or left side of the text node:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Match if the preceding node (not necessarily sibling) that is either
      a non-empty-space-text node or an <lb> is an <lb break='no'> -->
    <xsl:template match="text()[
        (preceding::node()[
            self::text()[normalize-space() != ''] or
            self::lb])
                [last()]
        [self::lb[@break='no']]
        ]">

        <!-- Trim whitespace on the left. Thanks to Alejandro,
            http://stackoverflow.com/a/3997107/423105 -->
        <xsl:variable name="firstNonSpace"
            select="substring(normalize-space(), 1, 1)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($firstNonSpace,
            substring-after(., $firstNonSpace))"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Match if the next node (not necessarily sibling) that is either
      a non-empty-space-text node or an <lb> is an <lb break='no'> -->
    <xsl:template match="text()[
        following::node()[
            self::text()[normalize-space() != ''] or
            self::lb]
               [1]
        [self::lb[@break='no']]
        ]">

        <xsl:variable name="normalized" select="normalize-space()"/>
        <xsl:if test="$normalized != ''">
            <xsl:variable name="lastNonSpace"
                select="substring($normalized, string-length($normalized))"/>
            <xsl:variable name="trimmedSuffix">
                <xsl:call-template name="substring-after-last">
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$lastNonSpace"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, string-length(.) -
               string-length($trimmedSuffix))"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <!-- otherwise output nothing. -->
    </xsl:template>


    <!-- Thanks to Jeni Tennison:
        http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200111/post00460.html -->
    <xsl:template name="substring-after-last">
        <xsl:param name="string" />
        <xsl:param name="delimiter" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($string, $delimiter)">
                <xsl:call-template name="substring-after-last">
                    <xsl:with-param name="string"
                        select="substring-after($string, $delimiter)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$string" /></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My assumption here, pending the answer to my "Next ambiguity" comment above, is that if there is an `<lb>` element *without* `break="no"`, that `<lb>` constitutes "surrounding text" in the sense that it serves as a boundary for ignoring whitespace.

### Sample input:

```
<test>
    <t1>
        This <emph>little <ref>tea </ref> </emph>
        <lb break="no" />
        pot, short and stout.        
    </t1>    
    <t2>
        This <emph>little <ref>tea </ref> </emph>
        <lb />
        <lb break="no" />
        pot, short and stout.        
    </t2>    
</test>
```

### Output:

```
<test>
    <t1>
        This <emph>little <ref>tea</ref></emph><lb break="no"/>pot, short and stout.        
    </t1>    
    <t2>
        This <emph>little <ref>tea </ref> </emph>
        <lb/><lb break="no"/>pot, short and stout.        
    </t2>    
</test>
```

This output is correct AFAICT. If not, please let me know why and I'll see about fixing it.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response. This is looking great! Thanks. I need to research the question about an <lb> without break="no" adjacent to one with it. I haven't fully tested this, but it seems to be working. I'm a little concerned about performance. I wonder if yamahito's approach starting from the <lb> element would be faster. In practice there will be many, many documents that have no <lb> elements at all, and far fewer that have break="no".

Comment: @JPM, my reading of http://www.tei-c.org/release/doc/tei-p5-doc/en/html/ref-att.breaking.html would indicate that `<lb break="yes"/>` should indeed provide a boundary to the whitespace-ignoring effect of `<lb break="no"/>`. `<lb/>` with no `break` attribute does not seem to be specific enough, in terms of the TEI standard, to let us know how to treat it; but maybe the conventions used in your application are that `<lb/>` with no `break` attribute is equivalent to `<lb break="yes"/>`? The latter would seem a reasonable convention.

Comment: The P5 guidelines (http://www.tei-c.org/release/doc/tei-p5-doc/en/html/CO.html) do say that `<lb>` with no `break` attribute is equivalent to `break="yes"`.

Comment: +1 for also putting in references to your sources! Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Try a selector like the following:</strike>

```
text()[matches(., '\S?\s*$') and not following::text()[matches('\S')] and following::lb[@break="no"]]
```

This is, of course, hideous and inefficient.  But may work. won't work because, as has been pointed out, you don't have matches().  I'll have another go:

OK, we're looking for four different scenarios:

- first preceding non-empty text element, if it ends in a space:

  lb[@break='no']/preceding::text()[normalize-space()!='' and string-length(substring-after(.,normalize-space()))!=0][1]
- empty text elements following the first preceding non-empty text element:

  lb[@break='no']/preceding::text()[normalize-space()='' and preceding::text()[normalize-space()!='']]
- empty text elements preceding the first following non-empty text element:

  lb[@break='no']/following::text()[normalize-space()!='' and string-length(substring-before(.,normalize-space()))!=0][1]
- first following non-empty text element, if it begins in a space:

  lb[@break='no']/following::text()[normalize-space()='' and following::text()[normalize-space()!='']]

Because you can't use union in xpath 1.0, you'll have to call a template from each of the above matches using this method.

Comment: He said he needed a solution in XSLT/XPATH 1.0, so `matches()` is not available.

Comment: Um... yes you can use union in XPath 1.0. Even in match patterns. By the way, interesting approach -- starting from the `lb[@break='no']` rather than from each `text()` node.

Comment: For the second scenario above, 'empty text elements following the first preceding non-empty text element', the XPath expression does not match the scenario description. Rather, the XPath expression will select empty text elements following *any* preceding non-empty text element. (This is the classic "select nodes between X and Y" problem.)

Comment: You can use unions, but there are some restrictions that were causing validation errors: multiple templates shouldn't be a big problem, tho'.

Comment: I think the bigger problem with this approach is that it ignores the lb[not(@break='no')] scenario you've noticed - well spotted!